# How to see all protected questions?

Tags: support, protected-questions

I will like to know if there is a way to see all protected questions related to one specific tag.

For example, I would like to see all protected questions which are tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Is there a way I can see those questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the data explorer to query this. Note however, it's only refreshed every Sunday.

Here's an example query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/653790

Note that it doesn't take into account questions which were protected and then unprotected; this will get you all questions tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) which were at one point protected. Feel free to further refine it

Comment: 10K users can see [list of protected questions at tools page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287081/165773)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/653803/protected-questions-by-tag?TagName=javascript) is an updated version of the SEDE query, which lets you enter the tag name as a parameter, and *only* includes questions which are protected <s>now</s> last Sunday.

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
select posts.id as [Post Link], pq.creationdate as [Protection date]
from posthistory as pq
inner join posts on pq.postid = posts.id
inner join posttags on posttags.postid = posts.id
inner join tags on posttags.tagid = tags.id
left outer join posthistory as uq
  on uq.postid = posts.id
  and uq.posthistorytypeid = 20
  and uq.creationdate > pq.creationdate
where pq.posthistorytypeid = 19
  and uq.posthistorytypeid is null
  and tags.tagname = ##TagName:string##
order by pq.creationdate desc
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a dedicated link for 10K users (for each relevant site):

https://stackoverflow.com/tools/protected-questions